# Подключение стороннего класса Yii -  failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, yii

Добрый день. Пытаюсь подключить сторонний класс в Yii. В папку Protected/vendors залил папку с классом. В начале контроллера пишу код

```
Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
require_once('phpbrowscap/Browscap.php');
```

Как только объявляю объект `$bc = new Browscap();` выдается ошибка

> include(Browscap.php) [<a
> href='function.include'>function.include</a>]:
> failed to open stream: No such file or
> directory

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Путь к классу верный, если переименовать, то выдает

> require_once(phpbrowsca1p/Browscap.php)
> [<a
> href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]:
> failed to open stream: No such file or
> directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@konstantin90](/users/17807/konstantin90)](/users/17807/konstantin90), Yii имеет миллион очень странных решений, и одно из них - это автозагрузчик, который вываливается с ошибкой, вместо того, чтобы передать управление следующему. Конкретно здесь он пытается загрузить класс Browscap, который, почему-то не появился после загрузки `phpbrowscap/Browscap.php`.

Comment: Понял, подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему?  
Код класса:   https://github.com/GaretJax/phpbrowscap/blob/master/src/phpbrowscap/Browscap.php

Comment: @konstantin90

    $bc = new phpbrowscap\PhpBrowscap;

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Спасибо! Завелась так:
$bc = new phpbrowscap\Browscap();

правда теперь кидает ошибку Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in Browscap.php on line 818

но это, наверное, вопрос другой темы...

Comment: @konstantin90 да, BrowsCap попытался отхватить больше оперативки, чем есть.

Comment: @Etki, более странное решение тут, это `Yii::import('application.vendors.*');`. Зачем грузить всю кучу расширений из `vendors`, если нужно только одно из них. Но, да, с автозагрузкой стороннего кода в yii всегда были танцы с бубном. Благо в yii2 автозагрузка через composer, и это снимает все проблемы.